# OperationalError with web.py on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I have been using web.py with Python 2.4. I've since migrated to Python 2.7 and am getting an error:

> OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

Is this related to web.py? The [webpy installation guide](http://webpy.org/installation) says:

> `web.py` supports Python 2.4 – 2.6 and has no immediate prerequisites.

Comment: This has to do with your database connection, not web.py.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid But i was not able to get this error in python2.4